# Multiple BeginGetResponse inside BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I have UI code that utilizes `BackgoundWorker` for processing of expensive operations.
Inside `DoWork` is the metod that sends multiple web requests to remote web-server via `BeginGetResponse`.

The UI part is:

```
 private void start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        if (bw.IsBusy != true)
        {
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Processing.FormWebRequests);
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Processing.FinishBw);
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
```

`DoWork` executes following:

```
public static void  FormWebRequests(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (webSites websiteitem in websites)
        {
            //Creation of webRequest object

            webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), webRequest);

        }
    }
```

And finally, callback method:

```
private static void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    using (HttpWebResponse response = wr.EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse)
        {
           //Parsing httpResponse
        }
}
```

Obviously, `BackgroundWorker` fires `RunWorkerCompleted` right after last `BeginGetResponse` sent. The problem is that I would like `BackgroundWorker` to fire `RunWorkerCompleted` after last `EndGetResponse` is finished.

Is this possible? Or should I use different async pattern?

Answer (score 0):

`BeginGetResponse` is already async. This method returns immediately. When the response is completed,  `FinishWebRequest` will be fired. So, you don't need to use `BackgroundWorker`.

This is Event driven.